# Upload data to iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icloud

I am trying to upload document to iCloud using the following code

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
NSURL* sourceURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:path];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[sourceURL path]]) {
    NSLog(@"File found!");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"File not found!");
}



NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
if (ubiq) {
    NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURL *destinationURL = [ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.png"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES
                                        itemAtURL:sourceURL
                                   destinationURL:destinationURL
                                            error:&error];
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Error while uploading the file: %@", error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"File ulpoaded successfully");
    }
else {
    NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
}
```

The file i am trying to upload exists (the "File found" is printed), but the uploading it to iCloud generates the following error

```
Error while uploading the file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1dd6bda0 {NSURL=/var/mobile/Applications/9F496F51-9DCA-4379-A62E-FFF7D7AB7385/VerticalSwipeArticles.app/test.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x1dd6c120 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that all your entitlements are correct and that you have the app marked for iCloud in the dev portal.

Comment: Yes i checked it and it's right

Answer (score 1):

Use GCD and call iCloud code (specially NSURL *ubiq =... line) from a different thread. Calling it on the main thread might block the app in some circumstances.

The way you construct your iCloud path looks weird to me. try this:

```
NSURL *destinationURL = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
```

Comment: Should i upload the file in a different thread too or just the NSURL* ubiq= ... line only?

Comment: I tried to do so and the following error is generated 

"The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"

Comment: @ahmedelbagoury i usually do all iCloud stuff on a different thread and get the main queue when posting UI updates/notifications etc. about your problem, I don't have a definite answer, does anything else related to iCloud work? can you store simple key-objects on NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore for example?

Comment: After this i have got the success method for upload , after then how can i retrieve my data from icloud ?